# Buscar imagem do banco de dados no php

Tags: php, mysql, imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Bom dia
Pessoal quanto ao código estou tentando buscar uma imagem que está no banco e trazer para a página, mas não está trazendo a imagem(Consulta de cadastro de pacientes).
Para a inclusão do cadastro de paciente com a foto, estou usando o código abaixo que está funcionando certinho, mas caso eu queira consultar um registro que tenha uma imagem, o que está errado em relação ao código abaixo ?
Na propriedade `defaultPreviewContent` está sendo usado a variável `$path` é o que contém o diretório + o nome do arquivo..
Não sei se estou sendo claro.
Fico no aguardo.
Rogério

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            var btnCust = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Add picture tags" ' + 
                              'onclick="alert(\'Call your custom code here.\')">' +
                              '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>' +
                              '</button>'; 
                          $("#avatar-2").fileinput({

                            overwriteInitial: true,
                            maxFileSize: 1500,
                            showClose: false,
                            showCaption: false,
                            showBrowse: false,
                            browseOnZoneClick: true,
                            removeLabel: '',
                            removeIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
                            removeTitle: 'Cancel or reset changes',
                            elErrorContainer: '#kv-avatar-errors-2',
                            msgErrorClass: 'alert alert-block alert-danger',
                            defaultPreviewContent:  '<img src= $path alt="Your Avatar" style="width:160px"> <h6 class="text-muted">Click para selecionar</h6>',  
                            layoutTemplates: {main2: '{preview} ' +  ' {remove} {browse}'},
                            allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar o código por escrito? o stackoverflow tem a opção de formatar o texto como código

Comment: Opa, bom dia. Ok editei o código, não sei se voce entendeu ? Obrigado

Comment: esse `$path` esta retornando algo?

Comment: Sim, está retornando o diretório + o nome do arquivo

Comment: Está retornando assim: ../img_cad_patient/4bb77467d1b8a75a05bdbb8bc1b14d4a.jpg

Comment: concatene a url do servidor com o path de onde a imagem está, meuservidor.com/img_cad_patient/4bb77467d1b8a75a05bdbb8bc1b14d4a.jpg  por exemplo

Comment: Mas é local, da minha máquina, ainda está em desenvolvimento...

Comment: ou então seria assim: 127.0.0.1/img_cad_patient/4bb77467d1b8a75a05bdbb8bc1b14d4a.jpg, isso ?

Comment: sim, desde que o caminho da imagem esteja dentro do servidor da aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está passando o `$path` no em um código javascript,você terá que abrir o php dentro do código, caso contrario, ele irá exibir `$path` em vez do conteúdo da variável.

Oque precisa ser alterado:

```
defaultPreviewContent: '<?='<img src="'.$path.'" alt="Your Avatar" style="width:160px"> <h6 class="text-muted">Click para selecionar</h6>'?>'
```

Comment: Conforme sua orientação, fiz assim:  defaultPreviewContent:  <?='<img src="'.$path.'" alt="Your Avatar" style="width:160px"> <h6 class="text-muted">Click para selecionar</h6>'?>,  mas não funcionou, simplesmente não trouxe a imagem

Comment: Quanto a variável $path, está assim: $path = "../img_cad_patient/".$arquivoFoto;

Comment: ja tentou pasar o `../img_cad_patient/4bb77467d1b8a75a05bdbb8bc1b14d4a.jpg` fixo no código?

Comment: Sim, já tentei e ai aparece a imagem....Estranho né...

Comment: ele não exiber nenhum erro no F12 do navegador?

Comment: Como assim F12 ? Não entendi...O inspecionar elementos ? Se é isso, vou ver agora...

Comment: quando você clica com o botão direito do mouse na página e seleciona "Inspecionar"

Comment: Opa, sim vi agora, está reportando o seguinte erro:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: poderia acrescentar um print com o erro, logo apos o seu código?

Comment: Oi coloquei a imagem.. Mas a imagem ficou em cima do código, foi mal. Não estou acostumado usar o stackoverflow...

Comment: No caso o código estou colocando assim: defaultPreviewContent:  <?='<img src="'.$path.'" alt="Your Avatar" style="width:160px"> <h6 class="text-muted">Click para selecionar</h6>'?>,

Comment: logo na frente do erro `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` clique onde está escrito `patient-edit-form.php?id=31:423`, provavelmente vai aparecer o erro de forma mais detalhada

Comment: Sim claro, mas nao consigo identificar..

Comment: fiz uma pequena alteração no código, tente colocar dessa forma: `defaultPreviewContent: '<?='<img src="'.$path.'" alt="Your Avatar" style="width:160px"> <h6 class="text-muted">Click para selecionar</h6>'?>'`

Comment: Bingo... Resolvido.. Muito obrigado.. Obrigadão mesmo....

Comment: Por nada, se tiver como definir minha resposta como correta eu ficaria grato, já que o problema foi resolvido :)

Comment: Aproveitando: Sabe me dizer como faço para trazer em um componente Select do html os registros que estão em PHP ? Na verdade, sei como trazer, mas como posso trazer somente o que foi salvo no banco e ao mesmo selecionar outros.

Comment: E como posso colocar aqui que sua resposta está correta ?

Comment: cria outra pergunta relacionado ao select do html, explicando oque você precisa e como está o seu banco e sua página que te ajudo. Acessa esse [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) aqui para ver como marcar a resposta como correta